# Clicking all elements found in List<WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click all of the instances of an element found by the class attribute found in an i tag within an anchor tag in the row of a dynamic table. Specifically, its a row with several cells and in the last cell there is a series of 4 links with either and X or an O. If the square is an X, it can be clicked and after a short wait, changes to an O. The links are written as follows:

```
<a class="foobar"><i class="dontNeedToClick"><i></a>
<a class="foobar"><i class="dontNeedToClick"><i></a>
<a class="foobar"><i class="needToClick"><i></a>
<a class="foobar"><i class="dontNeedToClick"><i></a>
```

When the needToClick element is clicked, the class would change to a dontNeedToClick element There are less than a hundred X's in a database of thousands of O's to scroll through, so something to automate clicking them would save a lot of time. I can successfully count the instances the element appears in the table, but when I put the elements into a List object using .findElements() and attempt to iterate through it, I get ElementNotVisibleException.

Here is my sample code so far:

```
// get the count of thumbs down accounts
    int elementsCount= driver.findElements(By.className("needToClick")).size();
    System.out.println("Amount of elements: " + elementsCount);

// loop and click through all elements found

    for (int x = 0; x < elementCount; x++) {
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("needToClick"));
        WebElement client = elements.get(x);
        client.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

I have tried using Iterator and get the same exception thrown at me.

```
        Iterator<WebElement> clickElement = elements.iterator();
        while (clickElement.hasNext()) {
            clickElement.next().click();
        }
```

I have also tried using a foreach loop.

```
    List<WebElement> thumbsDown = driver.findElements(By.className(expectedClass));

    for(WebElement element : thumbsDown) {
        element.click();
    }
```

I would use xpath but I am not very experienced with dynamic tables and haven't been able to find an approach that would fetch the row containing the element I'm looking for and other elements relative to it and figured a less than elegant approach such as just finding all the elements by the class name would suffice. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you miss a double qoute at this line `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("needToClick));` ? I add a comment because i dont think this is the cause of your problem,cuz you can't compile with the missing double qoute.

Comment: That was a typo in generalizing the code for a use not specific to mine. Thanks for pointing it out but yes, the code complies and runs up until the exception is thrown at me.

Comment: you should try to run the debugger to see when the exception occur, (e.g : when the first time the loop executed of sometime later). It is possible that the click event modify the elements list so findElements cannot find it.

Comment: is that a chrome/firefox feature or eclipse? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I mean debug your java code, because`ElementNotVisibleException` was thrown by the `findElements` function. If it was thrown sometime later in the for loop, may be the first click modify the list, so it can not find the class `needToClick` in later iteration.

Comment: Add description for what the click does in your question will be helpful

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML that you're trying to iterate over?  Could it be that those elements with needToClick class are not in fact visible on the page?  Selenium won't let you click on something that is in the DOM, but is not visible at the time you attempt to click on it...

Comment: updated the question with a better description of the scenario. @moilejter I inspected the document and the anchor element used for the button has a generic class for the four links in the row and I have to rely on the class name of an the "i" element contained within it to find it with selenium. I can accurately count the amount of X elements in the table and can tell because when I manually click one of them, the count generated by the first part of the code I wrote updates accordingly. That is a good theory though, I will try to research around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure elements you try to click is visible. If you don't care about visibility click with javascipt:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("needToClick"));
elements.forEach(e -> {
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", e);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(e,"class", "dontNeedToClick"));
    //if element have not only dontNeedToClick class use attributeContains
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(e,"class", "dontNeedToClick"));
});
```

Check if you can click one element and class changes:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("needToClick")).click();
```

if not try xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[i[@class='needToClick']]"));
//or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[i[contains(@class,'needToClick')]]"));
```

Comment: This solution does exactly what I need. The `wait.until` raises an exception but isn't really necessary for my needs so I commented it out. The forEach loop correctly clicks all of the links marked `needToClick`. Thanks for the help! If you could explain where `arguments[0]` comes from is that would be great as I more or less understand the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the exception being thrown when you iterate through the list, or when you attempt to generate the list?

If it's the former, what you need to do is re-generate the list after every click - even if you load a new page that's exactly the same, selenium will see the elements on the new page as 'different' and you won't be able to use any of the elements you found on the old page. (Edit: I looked through your loop again, and it seems like you're doing this part right. My guess would be you need to wait for the page to load fully)

If it's the latter, then you might need to wait for the page to load, and make sure that the elements you're trying to find all exist. In selenium you can set explicit or implicit timeouts, but I personally prefer `time.sleep(however many seconds)` since selenium might 'say' it's loaded before fully loading all the javascript.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The loop iterates "successfully" aka with no exception thrown when I comment out the `client.click();` code, and the count for the elements updates in my console when I manually click one of them. Really stumped by this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use xpath, as I saw your element in `<i>` tags

like this

```
//a[@class='foobar']//i[contains(@class,'Click')]
```

Code

```
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='foobar']//i[contains(@class,'Click')]"));
 for (WebElement tempEle : elements) {
  tempEle.click();
}
```

You can also use `if` with `break` in the  For each loop to seelct particular element

Comment: Using an IDE recorder I can successfully click what I want using the following xpaths: `//tr[262]/td[12]/a`, `xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='random date and time'])[1]/following::a[3]`, `xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='uniqueemail@domain.com'])[1]/following::a[3]`, `//div[@id='accountsGrid']/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[262]/td[12]/a`. The `tr` number corresponds to one of links I need clicked. If I could somehow scrape the row number from the List[WebElement] that would really help but I also have not been able to figure that out.

Comment: No unfortunately. I tried the following xpath `int elementsCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*a[@class='foobar']//i[contains(@class,'needToClick')]")).size();` and it failed to count the elements my initial code was able to.

Comment: Okay now try with for each

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select every Element of a List List just use a foreach-loop:

```
for(WebElement e : List<WebElement>){
   e.doThings();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int elementsCount= driver.findElements(By.className("needToClick")).size();
System.out.println("Amount of elements: " + elementsCount);

    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("needToClick"));

for (int x = 0; x < elementCount; x++) {
    WebElement client = elements.get(x);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

client.click();
    }

Answer (score -1):

List elements = driver.findElements(By.className("needToClick"));
elements.get(0).click();
It will work for the click event on web list Elements